# ionic angularjs jqlite addclass is undefined

Tags: angularjs, jqlite

As far as I understand, jqLite is embedded into angularjs but when I run

`$("#myid").addClass`

I get

`undefined`

I am able to get the element just fine by it's self but I can't run `addClass` on it. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must run,

```
angular.element(document.getElementById("myid")).addClass("classname")
```

else

```
angular.element(document.querySelector("#myid")).addClass("classname")
```

jQlite doesn't support `selectors` and also in angular `$` is not assigned to JQLite. Instead when you use `angular.element`, it will return you `JQlite` wrapped object.

Comment: This answer works. As an added question: In the chrome browser, after the page is loaded, I can see that `$` is assigned to something that supports `selectors` but it doesn't appear to be JQLite. Do you know what `$` is bound to by chance?

Comment: Chrome has implemented `$` and `$$` as short form of document.querySelector and document.querySelectorAll.